# Is the gluing of two sheaves a coproduct?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, schemes

Let $X$ be a curve. Consider the category which has as objects triples $(S,F,\alpha)$ where $S$ is a finite set of closed points in $X$, $F$ is a vector bundle on $X$, and $\alpha$ is a trivialisation of $F$ outside $S$. As morphisms we take
$$Hom((S,F,\alpha),(T,G,\beta)):=\{S\subset T, \phi:F|_{X\setminus (T\setminus S)}\xrightarrow{\sim} G|_{X\setminus (T\setminus S)}\mbox{commuting with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ on $X\setminus T$}\}.$$

Suppose that $S$ and $S'$ are disjoint sets of closed points of $X$, and to have triples $(S,F,\alpha)$, $(S',F',\alpha')$. Then we can use the trivialisations to build a gluing of $F$ and $F'$, since the two sets are disjoint.

Is this a coproduct in the category defined above? In fact, having a map from the two objects to another object $(T,G,\beta)$ is to have isomorphism between $G$ and $F$ outside $S'$, and between $G$ and $F'$ 
outside $S$. I would like to conclude invoking the uniqueness of the gluing of sheaves, but... does this suffice? I fear that there is some problem with the isomorphism, which could not be unique...

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your question, but maybe this may help: If $i$ denotes the closed immersion of $S$ in $X$ and if $j$ denotes the open immersion of $X\setminus S$ in $X$, then the category of sheaves on $X$ is equivalent to the category whose objects are triples $(F;G;\epsilon)$ where $F$ is a sheaf on $S$, $G$ a sheaf on $X\setminus S$ and $\epsilon: F\rightarrow i^*j_*G$ a morphism of sheaves on $S$.